# Special CSS shadow box &| other work-around suggestion

Tags: html, css, shadow

I'm writing some HTML/CSS and I need to create a special shadow that has a custom width & height around a div.

[image]

What's the best way to do it? Right now, I've been trying to use **two** overlapping `box-shadow`'s but I can't find a way to make it look like the image. 
I know I could just create two divs and slap them on each other by specifying custom heights and whatnot, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner, css only approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this for box-shadow. I wasn't sure if you wanted the green bar displayed as well. So I left it off.

There is a spread radius option in box-shadow that is often never used:

`/* offset-x | offset-y | blur-radius | spread-radius | color */
box-shadow: 60px 0 0 -30px #ccc;`

In this case you would set this to a negative radius in order to achieve your desired effect. Do the same for the opposite side and it should work.

```css
div{
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 
    60px 0 0 -30px #ccc,
    -60px 0 0 -30px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The other option is to use the `:before` or `:after` pseudos